# Proceso de registro y envío de link por email - Como validar el link

Tags: php, encriptación, base64

Tengo un formulario de registro, hecho en PDO, y cuando todo el proceso de registro está realizado, por último "armo" un mail que envío al correo electrónico donde le envío un link para terminar el proceso de registro. Hasta ahí todo bárbaro, pero me dejaron medio paranoico con el tema de seguridad y yo hasta el momento tenía este pedazo de código para formar el link de activación:

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/forms/activacion/activa.php?id='.$registro.'&val='.$token;
```

En $registro guardo el nuevo código de usuario con el que está almacenado en la base. En $token paso una cadena generada con md5 como para darle mas seguridad. 
Como se darán cuenta en activa.php hago la validación con

```
  if(isset($_GET["id"]) AND isset($_GET['val'])) {  
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];
    $token = $_GET['val'];
    $mensaje = validaIdToken($idUsuario, $token);
  }
```

en validaToken hago algo asi (por si les interesa)

```
function validaIdToken($id, $token){

    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT activacion FROM usuarios WHERE id = :valor AND token = :token LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(':valor', $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':token', $token);
    $stmt->execute();

    $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        if ($resultado['activacion'] == 1) {
            $msg = "La cuenta ya se activo anteriormente.";
        } else {
            if(activarUsuario($id)){
                $msg = 'Cuenta activada.';
                } else {
                $msg = 'Error al Activar Cuenta';
            }
        }
        } else {
        $msg = 'No existe el registro para activar.';
    }
    return $msg;

   }
```

Resumiendo: estoy queriendo cambiar esto, y se me ocurrió enviar este link ya con el id y el token preprocesado con

```
var=<?php echo base64_encode(id='.$registro.'&val='.$token);?>
```

y después en el activa.php hacer la inversa, hacer:

```
base64_decode($_REQUEST['var']);
```

**PREGUNTA 1** 
Estoy en la duda de, si hago esto, ¿es necesario generar el token o sólo con el id procesado con esta encriptación alcanza?

**PREGUNTA 2**
En el caso de que procese el id y el token, el var me quedaría una cadena del tipo:

```
"id=xxxxx&val=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

¿Cómo recupero el valor del token y del id ?

Comment: No hay nada más seguro que el "ruido". Si el valor de activación es un valor aleatorio, nadie puede activar la cuenta a no ser que reciba el e-mail (tiene acceso a la cuenta de e-mail) o a tu BD (con lo cual lo de la validación es el último de tus problema). Si tienes un valor que significa algo, encriptarlo está bien pero siempre puede haber alguien que averigüe el proceso y lo suplante. Si el valor es aleatorio eso es imposible.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta para incluir la codificación y decodificación base64 que me parece era el punto medular de tu pregunta. Publiqué mi respuesta antes de terminarla; una disculpa.

Comment: Jajajaja el **punto**. Editado, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**P1.** Base 64 no es un sistema de encriptacion, más bien de codificación. Mi recomendación es que generes siempre el token y en todo caso que prescindas del id si los token son únicos.

**P2.** Cuando hagas el decode necesitarás parsear los datos. Por lo que yo generaría una cadena como como esta o similar

```
 'my_id---mi_token'
```

Luego después de hacer el decode los separaría con un explode() por la cadena que elijas de unión (en el ejemplo --- ).

Es decir

```
 <?php 
 // Codificar
 $var = base64_encode($registro.'---'.$token);
 $url = 'mi.url.php?var='.$var;

 // decodificar
 $var = base64_decode($_GET['var']);
 $datos = explode('----', $var);
 echo $datos [0]; // registro
 echo $datos [1]; // token
```

Personalmente una cosa más que añadiría sería un tiempo máximo para la activación. Es decir en la base de datos guardaría la fecha y hora en la que se hizo el registro luego una vez que el usuario pulse el Link de activación con pararía dicha fecha con la actual para saber si ha pasado más más tiempo del límite de tiempo que determines.

Comment: excelente !!!...

Comment: @MNibor aún que parece que gusto más la otra respuesta. Aún que son casi iguales y yo respondí primero! ;) , gracias igualmente!

Comment: ah si ? perdona... no me di cuenta...

Answer (score 2):

**Respuesta 1:** Depende enteramente de ti, agregar una segunda variable es una pequeña capa adicional para verificar que le información que estás "inyectando" es correcta, en lo personal yo usaría ambas; el id y token.

**Respuesta2:** Estarías haciendo un request `GET` cuando des click al link que envíes por correo; tomando el siguiente link como ejemplo:

```
http://dominio.com/forms/activacion/activa.php?id=xxXxxxxX&val=yYyYyYYYyyy
```

Al script `activa.php` le estarían llegando las variables `id` y `val` como `$_GET`:

```
$_GET['id'];  // xxXxxxxX
$_GET['val']; // yYyYyYYYyyy
```

Si quieres envolver los valores en un BASE64 entonces mi recomendación es que los separes con un carácter seguro, digamos `|`:

```
$link = 'http://dominio.com/forms/activacion/activa.php?var=' . base64_encode($registro.'|'.$token);
```

Después en `activa.php`:

```
$valores = explode('|',base64_decode($_GET['var']));
$valores[0];  // xxXxxxxX
$valores[1];  // yYyYyYYYyyy
```